# Factory Method Pattern in Objective C: NSClassFromString()

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have identified an area in an application I am developing where the factory method pattern seems appropriate.  I am reasonably familiar with this pattern in other languages (C#, Java), but I was reading the book "Cocoa Design Patterns" and it contains a chapter on Dynamic Creation, which shows how to use the NSClassFromString() method.  Of this function, it says:

> This single function effectively reduces the well-known Factory Method pattern to a single line of code in many cases.

I am wondering whether I should use this dynamic creation method instead of a typical factory method pattern?  Does the dynamic creation method win over the normal method every time, or are there occasions where one is more suitable than the other?

Right now, I am leaning towards using a regular factory method pattern, but I was wondering what others think?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim in the book is a little strong, I'd say.

You should use `NSClassFromString` in two circumstances:

- You're reading the class name as a string at runtime.  Obviously if you get the class name as a string, you have to convert it to a class object somehow, and `NSClassFromString` is one way to do that.   You should probably be testing the string (or the returned class object) against a whitelist of allowable classes, if you don't trust the source of the string.
- You're weak-linking a framework and using an SDK/platform that doesn't support the `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE` feature.  Check out the [*SDK Compatibility Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html) for more information about this.

In any other circumstance, it's probably better to get the class object using an expression like `[MyClass class]`.  That way, you'll get an error at compile-time if the class doesn't exist (for example because you misspelled the class name).